# Then, how can we show that $\forall i,j\in \mathbb Z, s.t.:1\leq i<j\leq n$, $e_i\wedge e_j $ is a basis vector for $\wedge^2(V) $?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

Let $V$ be a n dimensional vector space. Suppose $x,y\in V, f,g\in V^*$. Define $f\wedge g(x,y) = det 
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
fx & fy \\
gx & gy \\
\end{array} } \right)$

Then, how can we show that $\forall i,j\in \mathbb Z, s.t.:1\leq i<j\leq n$, $e_i\wedge e_j $ is a basis vector for $\wedge^2(V) $? ($\wedge^2 (V)$ is the set of antisymmetric 2 forms on $V$, and it is also a vector space).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\omega$ be a 2 form. You need to write is as a linear combination of $e_i \wedge e_j$.  What is your guess for, say, the coefficient of $e_1 \wedge e_2$?

Comment: $\omega (e_i,e_j)$ right?

Comment: Right!  Now can you see why $\omega = \sum \omega(e_i,e_j)e_i \wedge e_j$?  Hint:  what is $\omega(v,w)$, when you express both $v$ and $w$ in the basis given by $e_i$, $e_j$ ?